# Options for debugging a thin hypervisor (VT-x)

Tags: driver, virtualization, low-level, hypervisor

I've a tiny (task-specific) hypervisor for windows 7 x64 (as a driver). I'm testing it under vmware. Unfortunately I'm at a point where vmware either hangs (100% cpu, non-responsive) or produces "cpu reached invalid state" error.

My options are:

1. test on another physical machine
2. test inside another hypervisor/emulator that allows nesting (and EPT)
3. ???
4. `PROFIT`

Regarding 2., which software supports nested VMX/EPT? It has to be opensource, preferably supported by LibVMI.

Regarding 3., am I missing something? Are there some secret vmware switches enabling extensive debug output, or a way to check why bare metal CPU entered an invalid state?

Comment: It has been a few weeks; do you still need an answer for this?

Comment: VMWare seems to support your usage. See, for example, https://communities.vmware.com/thread/478890. I think you'll find debugging easier under VMWare than on a bare machine.

Comment: I suggest that you focus on the invalid guest state problem first (assuming you can reproduce it), since trying to figure out a hang is a lot more tedious. Capture or dump the VMCS right before each guest entry, and compare it with the detailed VM-Entry checks in chapter 26 of the Software Developer's Manual. (This is also tedious, but at least it's finite.)